# AFSK Demodulation in Android

Tags: android, signal-processing

I am modulating my own AFSK signal in Android using this function

```
public static double[] MyFSK(char bit) //bit 1 or 0
{
    double[] a = new double[SamplesPerBit]; // SamplesPerBit =  44100 / 1200 (baudrate)
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
    {           
        if(bit == '1')
            a[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * C.FreqHigh / SamplesRate);
        else
            a[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * C.FreqLow / SamplesRate);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Now my problem is the demodulation part, I successfully used FFT algorithm to find the frequency, but FFT downside is its need for a long data stream (1024-2048 samples) in order to find the frequency, which causes a very low baud rate.

So is there any more suitable way to find the frequency with lower sample count ? for me to handle 1200 baud ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goertzel's Algorithm requires far fewer samples and is more performant than an FFT for your use case. It can be used to distinguish between two or more known frequencies. Here's a PDF about it (includes code samples)...

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse466/12au/calendar/Goertzel-EETimes.pdf

Comment: Code samples are gone, unfortunately. That's what happens when you don't put your code in your actual document, or you post a document somewhere that you can't assure will remain on the net.

Comment: well, I gave it a shot. It works; but it's pretty useless for even really slow baud rates. At 45.45 baud and 170 HZ freq-to-freq, it requires too many samples to resolve the bins to even have a *hope* of keeping up with the data. This is more a curiosity or something that would be appropriate for detecting if someone was holding down a touch-tone key or something line that. For data, it's ridiculously slow.